# Windows Phone: Detect the source from which the app is downloaded for eg. directly from store, mobile site app link etc

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Is there any way to detect the source from which the app is downloaded? For example if the app has been downloaded directly from the store or it was redirected to store from some mobile site. Something similar to `CampaignTracking` in Android. Any library which can detect this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a `Rate & Review` mechanism, use the `MarketlaceReviewTask` class. It is documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.tasks.marketplacereviewtask%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). Here's a simple method to do it:

```
MarketplaceReviewTask mrktreview = new MarketplaceReviewTask();
mrktreview.Show();
```

You can fire this code from a click event or something similar. This opens the rate and review page for your app, after it is published in the store. That is all Microsoft is providiing currently to help the developers. If you are looking for detailed tracking or instant bug detection (after the app is published), you can use third party services that can do this. I recommend [Appboy](http://www.appboy.com).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not.

As distinct from Android, Apps can only be deployed through the store (or a developer sideload) on Windows Phone. But there is no way to recognize whether a website hyperlinked to the store page or the user downloaded it directly via the store application.

Answer (score 0):

I found a few links regarding the same. `Flurry` provides the support for campaign tracking through its library. A few links help here.

Flurry http://www.flurry.com/

Distimo
http://www.distimo.com/conversion-tracking

Tapstream
https://tapstream.com/developer/windows-phone-sdk-documentation/
https://tapstream.com/developer/conversion-api/